# How and when the XACML engine execute obligations

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac

I want to know all the steps for the execution of obligation by the XACML enforcement engine (PEP, PDP, PIP, PAP) and when the execution is triggered.

example of obligation:

> Your medical record has been accessed by:
>         
>         
>           
>         
>       
>     
>   thanks

Answer (score 0):

The XACML engine generates the obligation / advice from the Policy. The PEP (Policy Enforcement Point) - not part of the engine - is responsible for implementing / enforcing the obligation. This typically happens via code / obligation handlers which the PEP owner is responsible for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on XACML 3 specification, obligation and advice expressions are triggered by a XACML engine(PDP) when evaluation of a particular node (policy set, policy or a rule) matches the decision defined in that particular node and only for a PERMIT or DENY decision.

E.g., When I have a permit rule that says, 'Alice can view medical records' and an obligation defined in the same rule which says 'Medical record has been accessed by Alice', the obligation will be triggered by the XACML engine only when the rule evaluates to a permit in this example.

It's upto PEP to use this value from PDP.